# Wix template sending tracking via fileusr to my site - causing Google Analytics to view traffic as referral

Tags: google-analytics, velo

My website is hosted on wix.com . Wix does not allow you to insert HTML code directly in the page of your web site. When I input HTML code, Wix inserts an iframe that is hosted from a different domain (filesusr.com). This iframe does not use Google Analytics tracking, so when the browser loads this iframe GA believes my customer has "left" my web site and gone somewhere else. When the iframe loads, the original source of the traffic is lost.

From the research I've done, it seems this Wix feature does not work with GA traffic tracking, and so there is no solution other than using a different hosting platform.

However, I'm sure you clever folk know otherwise!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, Wix is notorious for being a "widget" based platform that does not play nice with custom code. However, the whole GA different-origin thing is such a common request that they implement the tracker directly themselves if you plug your GA ID into your site settings. Any reason you are not using this? - https://support.wix.com/en/article/adding-your-google-analytics-tracking-id-to-your-wix-site. They also claim to support other custom tracking snippets - make sure you are pasting it into the ["Tracking & Analytics"  section](https://support.wix.com/en/article/about-tracking-tools-analytics) and not as a custom HTML widget.

If for some reason you can't or don't want to use the above methods, it used to be that you were just out of luck. There is a reason why Wix is not as favored as other platforms by digital marketers that need to implement tracking code. However, if you were really determined, you could probably implement a very custom GA tracker or any custom code through their new feature called [Corvid](https://support.wix.com/en/article/about-corvid-by-wix), which exposes internal APIs and extra coding features. How to do so is beyond the scope of this question, but the [`postMessage()`](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.HtmlComponent.html#postMessage) method is the normal way to pass messages from a parent to a child (iframe) container. Or you could use [`wix-fetch`](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-fetch.html), which is an internal version of the web API [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), to manually send a *hit* request to GA.